# Set Eclipse as the default program for opening a file on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

I'd like to set Eclipse as the default text editor on Ubuntu. However, when choosing the default program for opening .html files, I notice that Eclipse is not visible as one of the programs that can open this type of file. How can I set Eclipse as the default editor for .html files (and other file types as well?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Navigate to the file in Nautilus
2. Right click the file and select "Properties"
3. Select the tab: "Open With"
4. Select the application you want to use as default. *If you don't see it in the list select "Show other applications" and navigate to it and select it.*
5. Select "Set as default" in the bottom right.
6. Done